# Can javascript block all external calls outside the current domain?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to block or to intercept all external calls outside of the current domain on a website?

no images / javascripts ajax / script tags / iframes can reference anything outside the domain the files are hosted on?

This is for a custom template builder I'm working on, so it needs to handle a lot of oddball pages.

Comment: Look at `Content-Security-Policy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with Content Security Policy (CSP). You get to specify the domains you trust

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

You can add other "trusted" sources as you like.
If something tries to refer to something outside of these domains, an error message will be thrown.

You can find a nice intro to CSP [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#source-whitelists).

Comment: Now if I can just figure out how to do this for ie9 and below